# Run scheduled tasks chain

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, scheduled-tasks

1. I need run scheduled tasks one by one with different delays after previous task being executed.
   Example. There are a tasks list and delays list.

   ```
   toRun = {task1, task2, ..., taskn}
   delays = {100, 9, 22, ..., 1000}
   ```

Now I need run task1 throgh 100ms, task2 after task1 through 9ms, task3 after task2 through 22ms and so on.

2. I am using javafx. Task can use some UI update methods, like changing nodes positions. That forces me to use *Platform.runLater()* method, because if I don't, then I will have an exception "Not on FX application thread". As I know about this method it runs *Runnable* object after undefined amount of time. And depending of how much that time can vary I have two ways.

   2.1 Continue use *Platform.runLater()* method if call time < 1-2ms.

   2.2 Find another solution, which I don't have yet.

Shortly about actual task. I record user actions like mouse move, mouse click, and some application events. After that I need to replay those actions. So I go through every action using *ScheduledExecutorService.schedule()*, and inside of every action task put next task to scheduler. And something goes wrong every time, or just not feels stable enough.

I think the code here would be not so useful, because it two messy and a little bit big to quick figuring out

Comment: Do the individual tasks take a long time to run, or can they be run in their entirety (not including the delay) on the FX Application Thread?

Comment: @James_D, No, they are small enough. As I understand second question, yes, I think, they can be putted into and run fully at FX Application Thread. Those methods, while application not replay actions, called by events handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the actual tasks themselves, not including the delay, do not take a long time to run (so they may be executed in their entirety on the FX Application Thread), you can use a `Timeline` as follows:

```
Runnable[] tasks = { /* task1, task2, ..., taskN */ } ; // N elements
int[] delays = { 100, 9, 22, ..., 1000 }; // N-1 elements (delay after task1, ..., task(N-1)

KeyFrame[] frames = new KeyFrame[tasks.length] ;
int cumulativeMillis = 0 ;
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    frames[i] = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(cumulativeMillis), event -> tasks[i].run());
    if (i < delays.length) {
        cumulativeMillis += delays[i] ;
    }
}
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(frames);
timeline.play();
```

With this approach, there is no need to worry about multithreading: the `Timeline` takes care of the threading issues for you. Each task is executed on the FX Application Thread (but the pauses between them do not block that thread).

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect solution. But, I am interested also, what if task will be complex enough?

Comment: If the actual task takes a long time to run, then you should run it in a background thread, for example with `event -> new Thread(tasks[i]).start()`. In this case you must make sure that the code for the tasks executes anything that changes the UI via `Platform.runLater()`.